# laravel - rss display

Tags: php, laravel, rss

Welcome ! Can someone tell me how to display rss from another site on mine? Exactly this rss  link `http://awiacja.imgw.pl/rss/metar00.php?airport=EPWA` I'm using laravel 5.3

Regards and thank You for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most easy way is to use `file_get_contents`:

```
$rss = file_get_contents(http://awiacja.imgw.pl/rss/metar00.php?airport=EPWA);
return response($rss);
```

Comment: and it'll work on all shared hostings?

Comment: It should as far as I know. Are you having trouble using that function?

Comment: right know i'm developing on localhost so i'll check it in few days

Comment: ok and i have such input <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <rss version="2.0"> <channel> <title>Metar z pełnej godziny</title> <link><![CDATA[http://awiacja.imgw.pl/]]></link> <description> Komunikat METAR ze strony awiacja.imgw.pl </description> <item> <title>Metar G00 EPWA</title> <link><![CDATA[http://awiacja.imgw.pl/index.php?product=metar1h&aport=EPWA#k]]></link> <description> METAR EPWA 302000Z 17006KT 9999 BKN035 08/03 Q1025 NOSIG= </description> </item> </channel> </rss> how can i get only description?

Comment: For more advanced XML parsing (which you are doing right now) I would advice to look at the answer of siboc or start reading up on the following url: [XML parsing with php](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_xml_simplexml_read.asp)

Answer (score 3):

Searching for Laravel RSS readers provides a number of Laravel 5-compatible packages to do RSS parsing for you. For instance, https://packagist.org/packages/willvincent/feeds provides you a full example of working with the reader.

If, for some reason, you don't want to work with a Laravel package, there are non-Laravel RSS parsers or generic markup parsers for PHP that can do the same thing.

Or you could do your own parsing by using something like file_get_contents() or a curl call to grab the RSS feed and then use a basic regex or substr to grab the tags you care about.

In any case, you then have to pass that extracted data to your view for display. Presumably, your data would be in an array so you could just use a @foreach directive in the view and then display the items in a list or table or whatever you want.

```
<ul>
@foreach($data as $datum)
    <li>{{$datum['title']}}</li>
@endforeach
</ul>
```

The pre-made packages will save you a lot of time, though.

Comment: i tried to use it as instructed but i get this error: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Feeds' not found

Comment: fixed, forgot to add use Feeds

Comment: and i have Illegal string offset 'description' with this code `$feed = Feeds::make('http://awiacja.imgw.pl/rss/metar00.php?airport=EPWA',true);
        $data['data'] = array(
        'description'     => $feed->get_description(),
   );

        return view('home',$data);` and with this foreach loop `@foreach($data as $datum)
      <li>{{$datum['description']}}</li>
  @endforeach` when i change to `{{$datum->description}}` i get this error: `Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: You're passing it a nested array. So your foreach loop is just getting $data['data'] in the $datum variable. You should just set $data = array(...) and then change the call to {{ $datum->get_description() }}

Comment: `Call to a member function get_items() on string` and function `$feed = Feeds::make('http://awiacja.imgw.pl/rss/metar00.php?airport=EPWA');
        $data = array(
      'title'     => $feed->get_title(),
      'permalink' => $feed->get_permalink(),
      'items'     => $feed->get_items(),
    );
        return view('home',['data' => $data]); `

Comment: What's the code in your view?

Comment: `@foreach($data as $datum)
      <li>{{$datum->get_title()}}</li>
  @endforeach`

Comment: earlier i tried with get_description, get_items and same error

Comment: Try changing it to {{ $datum['title'] }} . 

Sorry, I've not worked with the package you're using so I'm just going off the examples he provides on his page.

Comment: Illegal string offset 'title'

Comment: You might try 
    foreach ($data['items'] as $datum) <li>{{ $datum['title'] }}</li> endforeach 
or 
    foreach ($data['items'] as $datum) <li>{{ $datum->get_title() }}</li> endforeach 

Otherwise, just var_dump($data) in the route and post what it gives you.

Comment: Feed url used in tute not working, so used google feed url instead https://news.google.com/news/rss

Comment: Hi, can you please tell if is there a way to add image in feed. I search but solution which I found are seems outdated.